# Need help getting started on dropdown menu using Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, flexbox

I need help with getting started or how to start my dropdown menu using flexbox with the code I have already. I have already started on the normal navigation bar from a tutorial i watched, but the tutorial didnt include a drop down menu, so I added one myself.

- Home
- About
- Portfolio

  Graphic Design

  Digital Portrait

  Illustrations
- Services
- Contact Me

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleButton')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbarLinks')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.navBar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #91CEC9;
    color: #FFF;    
}

.navbarLinks ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.navbarLinks li{
    list-style: none;
}

.navbarLinks li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 42px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navbarLinks li a:hover{
    background-color: #163640;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
        
        <div class="logo">
            <!--Jackie Gray-->
            <img src="images/Logo2.png" alt="jgray logo">
        </div>
        
        <a href="#" class="toggleButton">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        
        <div class="navbarLinks">
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Digital Portrait</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        
        </div>
    
    </nav>
```

Comment: You need to create and style your toggle button using CSS first of all. There is no CSS styling code for your toggle so its does not exist right now.

Answer (score 0):

This additional CSS code will create a mobile toggle button hamburger when the screen size is under 1400px. You will need to add the html code and css for the mobile nav menu and a few lines of javascript to make the toggle work as well.

```css
.navBar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #91CEC9;
    color: #FFF;    
}

.navbarLinks ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.navbarLinks li{
    list-style: none;
}

.navbarLinks li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 42px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navbarLinks li a:hover{
    background-color: #163640;
}


#nav-icon3{width:40px;height:45px;position:relative;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);-o-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg);-webkit-transition:.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:.5s ease-in-out;transition:.5s ease-in-out;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:25px;right:25px;}
#nav-icon3 span{display:block;position:absolute;height:5.5px;width:100%;background:#000;border-radius:7px;opacity:1;left:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);-o-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg);-webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;-o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;transition:.25s ease-in-out;}
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1){top:0px;}
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2){top:12px;}
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2){width:50%!important;}
@media screen and (min-width:1379px){
#nav-icon3{display:none;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1390px){
  
#nav-icon3{
  display:block!important;}
  .navbarLinks {display:none;}
}

.logo img {
  height:50px;width:50px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
        
        <div class="logo">
            <!--Jackie Gray-->
            <img src="https://global-uploads.webflow.com/5e157547d6f791d34ea4e2bf/5e17558f848f82e664c09d67_logo-dark.svg" alt="jgray logo">
        </div>
        
        <a href="#" id="nav-icon3">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        
        <div class="navbarLinks">
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Digital Portrait</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        
        </div>
    
    </nav>
```